# Adding a page to the history in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I was wondering if it was possible to have a Google Chrome extension have sort of a hidden tab, that is directed to an inputted URL. For example, if I wanted to go to www.google.com then in the background the tab's URL would be www.google.com. The only way you could verify this is by checking your browsing history. Is this possible? Are there other ways to approach this?

My goal is to basically go to a URL and add it to the history, but keep this process hidden from the user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add an entry to the user's history? This is possible in JavaScript using the [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) function.

Example: `history.pushState({}, "Google", "http://google.com")`

Parameters:

- `state object`: Can be used to store data inbetween the different "states", or pages.
- `title`: The new title of the page
- `url`: The URL

However, there's a restriction:

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception.

Comment: Is there a method to bypass this restriction? I'd like it so my current url is different than the new one

Comment: I don't think that's possible. After all, it would enable anybody to add shady websites to your browser history.